# cbimport not importing file which is extracted from cbq command

Tags: json, jq, couchbase, couchbase-java-api

I tried to extract data from below [cbq](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/tools/cbq-shell.html) command which was successful.

`` cbq -u Administrator -p Administrator -e "http://localhost:8093" --script= SELECT * FROM `sample` where customer.id=="12345'" -q | jq '.results' > temp.json; ``

However when I am trying to import the same data in json format to target cluster using below command I am getting error.

`cbimport json -c http://{target-cluster}:8091 -u Administrator -p Administrator  -b sample -d file://C:\Users\{myusername}\Desktop\temp.json -f list -g %docId%`

````
JSON import failed: 0 documents were imported, 0 documents failed to be imported
JSON import failed: input json is invalid: ReadArray: expect [ or , or ] or n, but found {, error found in #1 byte of ...|{
    "requ|..., bigger context ...|{
    "requestID": "2fc34542-4387-4643-8ae3-914e316|...],```

    ```{
    "requestID": "6ef38b8a-8e70-4c3d-b3b4-b73518a09c62",
    "signature": {
        "*": "*"
    },
    "results": [
    {
        "{Bucket-name}":{my-data}
    "status": "success",
    "metrics": {
        "elapsedTime": "4.517031ms",
        "executionTime": "4.365976ms",
        "resultCount": 1,
        "resultSize": 24926
    }
````

It looks like the file which was extracted from cbq command has control fields details like **RequestID, metrics, status etc**. Also json in pretty format. If I manually remove it(remove all fields except {my-data}) then put in a json file and make json unpretty then it works. But I want to automate it in a single run. Is there a way to do it in **cbq command**.

I don't find any other utility or way to use **where** condition on [cbexport](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/tools/cbexport-json.html) to do that on Couchbase, because the document which are exported using cbexport can be imported using [cbimport](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/tools/cbimport-json.html) easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the cbq command, you can use the --quiet option to disable the startup connection messages and the --pretty=false to disable pretty-print.  Then, to extract just the documents in cbimport json lines format, I used jq.

This worked for me -- selecting documents from travel-sample._default._default (for the jq filter, where I have _default, you would put the Bucket-name, based on your example):

```
cbq --quiet --pretty=false -u Administrator -p password --script='select * from `travel-sample`._default._default' | jq --compact-output '.results|.[]|._default' > docs.json
```

Then, importing into test-bucket1:

```
cbimport json -c localhost -u Administrator -p password -b test-bucket1 -d file://./docs.json -f lines -g %type%_%id%
```

cbq documentation: https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/tools/cbq-shell.html

cbimport documentation: https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/tools/cbimport-json.html

jq documentation:
https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Basicfilters

Comment: It worked. Thanks.